# NEVPNManager in OSX 10.11 - how to set up IKEV2 VPN connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, vpn

I want to create (Xcode 8.2, OSX 10.11) a IKEV2 VPN Connection with NEVPNManager.

```
//  setup protocol
NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIKEv2 alloc] init];
p.serverAddress = vpnServer.address;
p.remoteIdentifier = vpnServer.address;
p.useExtendedAuthentication = NO;
p.disconnectOnSleep = NO;

p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret;
p.sharedSecretReference = [SHARED_SECRET_REF];

NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];
[manager loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        // post error notification
    } else {
        manager.enabled = YES;
        [manager setProtocolConfiguration:p];
        [manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if(error) {
                // post error notification
            }
            else {
                NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];
                NSError *startError;
                [manager.connection startVPNTunnelAndReturnError:&startError];

                // Error Handling
            }
        }];
    }
}];
```

Strange observations:

- [NEVPNManager sharedManager] is grabbing other mac app's configuration if there is any;
- No authentication POPUP from mac throughout the connection;
- Same lines of code are working just fine in iOS.

Anything I did wrongly in the code?